# PHP - Concatenate object class name

Tags: php, concatenation

Is is possible to concatenate an object's name?
The below doesn't seem to work..

Trying to call $node->field_presenter_en;

```
$lang = 'en';

$node->field_presenter_.$lang;

${$node->field_presenter_.$lang};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
$field_presenter = 'field_presenter_'.$lang;
$node->$field_presenter;
```

This is called variable variables. More information here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Edit:
The user nickb has suggested a much more elegant solution below, and I will incorporate into this answer for easier reading (nickb: please let me know if you want me to remove this):

```
$node->{'field_presenter_'.$lang}
```

Comment: nickb's `$node->{'field_presenter_' . $lang}` seems to be the best answer but I guess Ynhockey is also correct! thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
$field_presenter = 'field_presenter_'.$lang;
$node->$field_presenter;
```

Comment: Was trying to improve Ynhockey's answer but we edited at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class A {
    public $prop = 'hello';
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->{'pro' . 'p'}; // hello
```